# NoSectionError while running reddit-auto-respond

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./responder", line 56, in <module>
    r = Responder()
  File "./responder", line 28, in __init__
    self._r = praw.Reddit('Auto responder bot by /u/kragniz')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 105, in __init__
    **config_settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/config.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.custom = dict(Config.CONFIG.items(site_name), **settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 347, in items
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Auto responder bot by /u/kragniz'
```

Here is the program https://github.com/kragniz/reddit-auto-respond

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.NoSectionError)

Comment: Seems like you're not correctly configuring the program. You should look at the [example](https://github.com/kragniz/reddit-auto-respond#example-config) and file a bug with the project if it's incorrect.

Comment: The parameters to instantiate praw.Reddit doesn't seem correct: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html

Comment: Also note that this library hasn't been updated since 2013... you might want to try a different one.

Comment: Ok so I really don't know much python ( just know the basics of cpp ). Now I get error 'Reddit' object has no attribute 'get_unread'. So I'm assuming this is because this is old? Do you know any other library dimo414 ? Thanks!